# How can I extract a certain value of an attribute node in XPath?

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML code snippet:

> `<td><span class="form rating **xyz**">text</span></td>`

I want to have the attribute value of class but I only want the attribute values which start with 'form'.
How can I do this?

My approach so far:

> //span/@class

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//span[starts-with(@class,"form")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a predicate and use the `starts-with()` function to test the value:

```
//span/@class[starts-with(.,"form")]
```